# PHP session check

Tags: php, session

This is my code at the top of a secure page.  It always redirects to the header page.  If I uncomment the echo line it will display the correct user id so the id exists.  Any suggestions?

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']));
{   
    //echo "this is the id " .$_SESSION['user_id'];
    header("Location: signup");
  exit();} 
?>
```

Thanks Scott

Comment: Is your salary inversely proportional to the number of linebreaks? If not, please don't put `}` in the same line as a statement and don't put statements in the `<?php` line...

Comment: if a sessions is set you can check for it's value to be empty - "" - and maybe since an empty userid can be 0 also "0", this is not all tho' isset only checks if the $_SESSION['user_id'] is set and does not check if it's value is empty or filled in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']));
                                 ^ remove this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: signup");
    exit();
}
?>
```